# Collection filter With null and attribute value matched

Tags: collections, orm, magento-1.7

I am trying to get the products which match certain attribute values + `Null` in product collection. I have tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('length', NULL);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('length', array('in' => array(115, 116)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array(
                        array(
                            'attribute' => 'length',
                            'null' => true
                        ),
                        array(
                            'attribute' => 'length',
                            'finset' => array(115,116)
                        )
                    )
            );
```